# Consequences of negating Russell's infinity axiom in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic, infinity

Apologies in advance for another curious question.

From my research, it is clear that for any natural number we can construct a model that would entail a sentence such that there is the same number of elements in the domain of that model.
So, why not generalize this by using the negation of Russell's infinity axiom as a sufficient means to achieve the same ends (i.e. the entailment of any sentence in a finite domain)?

Comment: What is Russell's infinity axiom?

Comment: [Infinity axiom](https://www3.nd.edu/~jspeaks/courses/2007-8/43904/_HANDOUTS/Russell-logicism.pdf) and its negation are not "logical" axioms, because valid formulas are the mathematical counterpart of "logical truth", i.e. formulas that are true in every domain, whether finite or infinite. But obviously you can imagine a math theory of "finite" structures, imposing axioms that rule out infinite domains.

Comment: See [Principia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/#PartIIProlCardArit) *120.03 for Axiom of Infinity: The Axiom of Infinity asserts that all inductive cardinals are non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a sentence which is satisfied in exactly the finite structures. By the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem)$^1$, no such sentence exists **in first-order logic**. The crucial point is that a structure may be "wrong about itself." The classic example of this is [the existence of nonstandard models of first-order Peano arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815545/what-is-an-example-of-a-non-standard-model-of-peano-arithmetic): these are discrete ordered semirings which satisfy the first-order induction scheme, so "think" that all their initial segments are finite, yet "from the outside" have infinite elements. A first-order "axiom of finity" may rule out obvious infiniteness-es, but it won't be able to genuinely ensure that the structure in question is finite.

Of course this is a limitation of first-order logic specifically. In [second-order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) for example we can indeed write down a sentence true in exactly the finite structures. But there are good technical reasons for wanting to stick to first-order logic; ultimately compactness (and its "cousin in limitation," the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem) is a **good** thing to have.

---

$^1$Specifically, suppose $\varphi$ is a first-order sentence true in structures of arbitrarily large cardinality. Then the theory $$\{\varphi\}\cup\{\exists x_1,...,x_n(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ is finitely satisfiable, hence by compactness has a model. But such a model must be infinite.