# Are there Nonstandard Models of Arithmetic that don't Add Additional Axioms?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, incompleteness

Apologies if this is an elementary question that should have been obvious to me. I am learning about these topics very much from the perspective of an outside hobbyist, and am not a wizard of logic.

Do all non-standard models of PA add extra axioms? And if they do, doesn't that mean that the PA axioms do define a unique model in some sense? It's just that other models also satisfy those axioms (?).

Comment: "Do all non-standard models of PA add extra axioms? " No; [non-standard models of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) are structures that satisfy all PA 
 axioms but have additional elements outside the initial segment. This is due to the fact that first-order axioms for arithmetic do not "identify" the corresponding model up to isomorphism i.e. the first-order theory of arithmetic is not [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_theory).

Comment: But from that same Wiki page, the way it proves the existence of at least one non-standard model via the Compactness Theorem seems to involve adding infinite axioms. That's why I had this impression.

Comment: I think I understand though that this isn't necessary. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an example of a non standard model of Peano Arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815545/what-is-an-example-of-a-non-standard-model-of-peano-arithmetic) It contains, for example, the ultra power construction.

Comment: You may be able to add additional axioms to PA that exclude the standard model of arithmetic. Not sure what those might be though.

Comment: @eyeballfrog The usual example: not(Con(PA)). By Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, adding this to PA gives a consistent theory. But the standard model certainly doesn't satisfy it. (Because if you believe there *is* a standard model--or any model at all of PA--then you believe PA is consistent.)

Comment: " doesn't that mean that the PA axioms do define a unique model in some sense?" We know that there are other models (see linked post), from which we conclude that PA axioms do **not** define a unique model. Having said that, in order to "describe" how those "rogue" models looks like we have to work in a suitable "environment" with further assumptions, simply because all that is provable according to PA cannot do it.

Comment: In general, the existence of non-standard models of arithmetic has virtually nothing to do with the incompleteness of PA. Using compactness or ultrapowers, you can construct non-standard models of complete arithmetic which satisfy exactly the same first order sentences as the standard model despite not being (anywhere near) isomorphic to the standard model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate, there are several ways to show the existence of a nonstandard model of PA. The proof you've seen adds a new constant $c$ plus axioms $c>1$, $c>1+1$, etc. The ultraproduct construction takes a different route.

I don't know that I'd really describe the "$c>1+\ldots+1$" argument as adding new axioms, though. Technically that's true. But the new axioms are all about a brand new constant, and don't say anything about the standard integers.

Another way to prove the existence of non-standard models is to add an axiom like $\neg\text{Con(PA)}$ to PA. The resulting system is consistent by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, and so has a model $N$. Since the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies Con(PA), $N$ must be nonstandard. That's more clearly a case of "adding a new axiom".

One says that $\mathbb{N}$ and $N$ are not *elementarily equivalent*, i.e., don't satisfy the sentences of L(PA) (the language of PA). (Note that L(PA) does not include the extra constant $c$.) So $\mathbb{N}$ and $N$ do not "satisfy the same axioms" in any sense.

The comments also mentioned that PA is not $\aleph_0$-categorical. This is a somewhat different (but related) issue. $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ is so-called "true arithmetic" (or "full arithmetic"): the set of all sentences of L(PA) that are true for $\mathbb{N}$. (While we have no way of deciding, in general, exactly which sentences belong to $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, it's still interesting theoretically.)

Both the "$c>1+\ldots+1$" argument and the ultraproduct construction show that there exists a model, call it $M$, of $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ that is nonstandard. So $M$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are elementarily equivalent but not isomorphic.

We can also insist that $M$ is countable. That's what "not $\aleph_0$-categorical" means: two non-isomorphic countable models. So not just PA, but even $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ is not  $\aleph_0$-categorical.

So PA fails to define a unique model in two senses: there are other countable non-isomorphic models, and even stronger, there are other non-elementarily equivalent models.